# Can I download and install delphi 7 free trial for testing purpose?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Can I download and install delphi 7 free trial for testing purpose. As it is mentioned in embarcadero sites that they have stopped support for delphi 7 and its not available for download. Actually I have some old project written in delphi 7 and I want to run that.

What is the possible solution for my problem?

Comment: Try to ask Embarcadero... Delphi 7 download is available only for registered users and there is no trial version of it available anymore.

Comment: @TLama - Is it mean there is no way to download delphi 7 now? Embarcadero is saying this. Now how can I test my delphi 7 application and migrate it to Delphi XE4?

Comment: You can get older versions listed on [`this page`](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi/previous-versions), but first you *should* get a license to the latest Delphi (it doesn't have to be the latest, but why would you buy an older version if you can get all the older with the latest one). Also I'd suggest you to read carefully what your local distributor offers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delphi trial versions are only available for the latest version of the software. Since you already have code from an existing project, a trial version for evaluation is not what you need. What you need is to purchase the full version and gain access to old versions that way.